# ¿Cómo acceder a un objeto del localStorage mediante código Java?

Tags: javascript, java, script, local-storage

Muy buen día a todos, estoy tratando de acceder a un objeto de Javascript almacenado en el localStorage previamente.
Consultando me he encontrado esta solución (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059716/access-javascript-object-property-using-java), pero al tratar de implementarla, recibo el siguiente error:

javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "localStorage" is not defined in  at line number 1 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)

Mi Código es el siguiente:

```
String script = "var identificacion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identificacionAfiliado'))";
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.eval(script);
Object nativeObject = jsEngine.get("identificacion");
```

El error se produce en la línea 4 (jsEngine.eval(script))

Agradecería mucho me indiquen por favor la manera correcta de hacer lo que necesito, así no sea de esta forma. Muchas gracias por el tiempo y atención :)

Comment: El objeto [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), que es parte de la [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), es accesible en un entorno manejado por el Navegador, en el lado cliente. ¿Quieres tener acceso al mismo desde el lado Servidor?.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si!, es posible realizar esto?

Comment: No, no es posible, desde el Servidor, leer directamente el objeto Storage. Debes enviar la información desde el cliente al servidor mediante una llamada Ajax. Recuerda que el cliente es el código que se ejecuta en el navegador. Tal como desde el cliente no tienes ninguna forma de acceder a las variables o entrono del servidor. Lo suyo es comunicarlos mediante llamadas Ajax (peticiones `http`). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por la explicación, que tengas un buen día!